# In which doctrine repository should I put a query with various relationships?

Tags: doctrine-orm, repository-pattern

I have recently started to use Doctrine, and I love it, but I still have some issues to find out in which repository suits better to write a query that must join several relationships.

Let's think in an example. There is a project where a Customer entity is associated with many Purchases and, at the same time, each Purchase is associated with a Product.

If we need to query all the Products that have been bought by Customers from a concrete country like Spain, for example, this query is going to return Products as its root entity. So, I feel like it should be put in the ProductRepository.

**Edit: Added an example in order to make it easier to understand the case.**

An example of this query using the QueryBuilder would be like this:

```
public function findAllProductsSoldInCountry(Country $country)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->innerJoin('p.purchases', 'pp')
       ->innerJoin('pp.customer', 'c')
       ->where($qb->expr('c.country', ':country'))
       ->setParameter('country', $country);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But, I still don't feel quite comfortable with this approach. It makes the developer to define extra bidirectional relationships that, at least to me, aren't always needed. In this case we have a relationship between the Product and its Purchases but maybe in our entire application we haven't any call to `getPurchases()` in a Product, or adding and removing Purchases directly from a Product instance.

Summing up, there is any rule of thumb to decide in which repository should be put a query that joins several entities like in the example?

Comment: I would always save it in the repository of the entity that is on the toplevel. In this case in the `CustomerRepository` as you need the products of a user. We are querying a `User` and not a `product`. Nevertheless I'm really curious to what others will do.

Comment: Why? If you put it in the CustomerRepository, how would you return an array of Products? Doctrine makes you to select always the root entity unless you define a manual JOIN bypassing the relationship. I do have a lot of queries like this using the approach you have said, but in all of them I have to massage the result or use the trick I've mentioned above. I don't think that's neat, so, what am I missing? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this situation, go **up** or **down** the line of entities.

### Down

The way down is were we start at the `Customer`, by getting all its **purchases** and lastly get all the **products** of those **purchases**.

### Up

On the way up, start at the `Products` where we want the products of every `Purchase` made by a certain `Customer`.

### My way of handling it

Most of the time I use the entity objects to get certain results, I try to avoid as much **DQL** as possible as I like to work **OO**. If you have a good schema and relations between your entities, they will contain **collections**, based on those collections you should be able to get the result you are looking for. Well lets say we need all the **products** of the `Customer`, so we will use its `Purchase` **collection**. Now loop through this collection and add every product to an array. Ofcourse you can use **DQL** to return the same result. But without the main entity, `Customer` you will come nowhere of collecting **products**.

### So what and why?

Notice that in some cases using just entity objects and looping through alot of collections can be bad as **Doctrine** **ORM** needs to query alot in that case use **DQL**. So please be aware of the performance it costs using **Entities against DQL**. But to let you know there isn't really a good or bad point of where to put those DQL statements. Ofcourse I get your point of storing the query in your `ProductRepository` as you will return **Products**. Just speak with your team about this and write down some rules of consistency. Also take the performance in consideration.

### Conclusion

So choose a way to work with. The way down I would use Entity Collections, but the way up I would store in `ProductRepository`. So which way do you prefer? Notice that the way down could consist of three (sub-)queries, while the way up can consist of one query.

#### Queries

#### On the way down

1. Get the user
2. Get the purchases of this user.
3. Get the products of those purchases.

The use of collections could provide some function like this:

```php
public function getProductsOfUser($userId) {
    $products = array();
    $user = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Customer')->find($userId);
    $purchases = $user->getPurchases();
    foreach($purchases as $purchase) {
        $product[] = $purchase->getProduct();
    }
    return $products;
}
```

Notice that this function can be added to a repository if needed, like `CustomerRepository`.

#### On the way up:

1. Get products where we want the products of every Purchase made by a certain Customer.

Using a query function:

```php
public function getProductsOfUser($userId) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT product FROM Products product LEFT JOIN product.purchases purchase WHERE purchase.userId = ?1');
    $query->setParameter(1, $userId);
    $products = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough in the question. If I haven't, please let me know and I'll edit it. In the example what I would like to retrieve are all the Products that have been bought by users in a concrete country. It is more a statistics query than a logged-in Customer query. These kind of queries are more frequent in a backend website. Many thanks for your answer, it is a very good answer for the use case you have explained but, I'm sorry it is not related with my doubt.

Comment: No problem at all, it wasn't really clear indeed. So you could update your question but nevertheless I learned something myself here ;) Well I hope it can provide some use to others. @jorgonor you might give an example of your query to make your question stand out a bit more.